# How to set a timer in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I am making a website for auction. I want to set a clock of 24 hours for every item. The clock time should be the server's time. If a user visits the site it should show the time remaining for that item. I want to do it in ASP.Net. I couldn't find any way to do it.

Comment: I assume you got your items stored in some kind of database, I think you can just add a column (if you havent alread) that represents the item's creation date; on the page that shows that item you simply subtract that creation date from the current date and check whether the difference is smaller or bigger than 24 hrs and hide/show the clock/item/whatever appropriately

Comment: Anyhow you need to provide more details to make it possible to really help you ;) We need at least some code snippets/sketches of your functionality/failed tries/... to see where you are stuck and what to do about it.

Comment: See this- this might help you!! http://forums.asp.net/t/1085601.aspx?Displaying+a+Countdown+of+time+remaining+using+AJAX+timer+control

Comment: Thank you so much...!!! I was thinking the same thing. I have not coded it yet just planning how to do it. @DrCopyPaste

Comment: you're welcome, just so you know: those kind of questions are usually not liked very much on stackoverflow, this place is mainly about solving problems/errors with already written code, I am not entirely sure but imho http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for general how-to questions

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a new page and switch to Design view.

If the page does not already contain a ScriptManager control, in the AJAX Extensions tab of the toolbox, double-click the ScriptManager control to add it to the page.
Timer Control Tutorial Step 1

In the toolbox, double-click the Timer control to add it to the Web page.
Timer Control Tutorial Step 2
```

plz  see This Web : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx